# Validate XML Against XSD

Tags: java, xsd

Looking for some confirmation that the below is the most efficient Java solution to validate a XML String against a schema.  Any other ways which are more efficient memory or performance wise?

```
private boolean isXMLValid(String XSDPath, String XML) {
        final SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        try {
            final Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(XSDPath));
            final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes())));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardly. You may get some minor improvements by reusing `SchemaFactory` (attention: not thread-safe) and `Schema` (immutable, thread-safe), but it's almost it. If you switch from `String XML` to something more streamy and use StAX you may get some memory improvements as well.

Comment: just for some context, this validation is sitting behind a REST API which will be called by another application to validate their XML so I'm not sure if I can get more streamy but let me know if you have any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: `ServletRequest` has a [`getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) method.